# Is there a WebClient object that can be used in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Is there a WebClient object that can be used in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the "standard" WebClient. See an example [here](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/monotouch-isoflair.html). Someone reported that https is problematic in monotouch so you may find a workaround [here](http://redth.info/2009/09/08/monotouch-https-post/)

**EDIT** https (SSL/TLS) support has been available in MonoTouch for a few years now

Answer (score 2):

A full sample that shows http, https using the .NET APIs as well as one using the Cocoa API is available in:

- [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/HttpClient)

The short sort story is: just use System.Net.WebRequest as you would with regular .NET